# Write contents of text file to an array of file blocks (512 Bytes) in C++

Tags: c++, file, io

I am trying to separate a 5 KB text file into a File array of 10 blocks, which are each 512 Bytes.

I have the file loading properly and writing to a char array but I don't understand what is happening at `while(infile >> temp[i])` below. **Does that mean "while test1.txt still has characters to write, write it to `temp[]`"?**

Basically, I want characters 0 to 511 in `input1.txt` to load into `temp[]` then store `temp` in `fileArray[0]`. And then characters 512 to 1023 to load into `temp[]` and then be stored into `fileArray[1]` and so on. If the file is shorter than 5 KB, fill the rest of the items in `fileArray[]` with 0's.

Code:

```
    FILE* fileArray[10];
//something like for(int a = 0; a < fileArray.length; a++)
    ifstream infile;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char temp[512];
    infile.open("inputFiles/test1.txt");  //open file in read mode.. IF FILE TOO BIG, CRASHES BECAUSE OF TEMP
    while (infile >> temp[i])//WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?
        i++;

    k = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << temp[i]; //prints each char in test1.txt
    }
```

**New Code:**

```
FILE* input = fopen(filename, "r");
if (input == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading OR %s is a directory which is fine\n", filename, filename);
    return;
}

FILE **fileArray = (FILE**) malloc(10 * 512); //allow files up to 5.12KB (10 sectors of 512 Bytes each)
                     //load file into array in blocks of 512B
                     //if file is less than 5.12KB fill rest with 0's

    std::filebuf infile;
infile.open("inputFiles/test1.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    outfile.open(fileArray[a], std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    int block = 512 * a;
    int currentBlockPosition = 0;
    while (currentBlockPosition < 512) {
        std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&infile[block + currentBlockPosition]), {},
            std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(&outfile));


        //input[block * currentBlockPosition] >> fileArray[a];
        //currentBlockPosition++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE].  It is very likely that `FILE*` is a mistake.

Comment: `FILE* fileArray[10];` are you planning on opening 10 files 512 bytes each?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes

Comment: Your **New Code** looks like C while you tagged and titled your question as C++. This is very confusing.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thanks, I updated again but am still concerned about `FILE **fileArray = (FILE**) malloc(10 * 512);`. Is that type of file array specific to C or will it work in C++ too?

Answer (score 0):

while (infile >> temp[i])//WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?
        i++; // This is means while there exist data in the file put this data in temp array

and I think it is good idea to take the whole data from the file and then split array

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you're right, I added a **New Code** section in my answer.